# How to avoid exception if the text file is already open

Tags: c#

I am learning C# and opening a text file using the following code.

```
 string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"\\127.0.0.1\Temp\players.txt");
```

The same text file is also being opened by other applications also and sometimes the application throws exception when the file is already opened by the other application.

I want to wait till the file is closed and than open it

Comment: Simply, you can't prevent this type of exceptions. You have to catch them and retry.

Comment: Do you see this question with answers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use

Comment: If a file/resource has already a lock, you can't obtain a new lock on it before the previous lock is being released.